# systrace only records subset of time requested

Tags: android, systrace

for example when I record a systrace using the following command line:

`python systrace.py -o mytrace.html -a my.app.package.name -t 45`

instead of showing data for the entire 45 seconds it only shows 5.6 seconds. I have a similar issue when i trigger systrace the Android Studio profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace data probably filled up the buffer (8 MB by default). You can set a bigger buffer size by using the `-b N` or `--buf-size=N` command option, where `N` is the number of kilobytes.

Alternatively you can use Android Studio Profiler to [record](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#method_traces) a System Trace, which lets you [config](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#create-configuration) buffer size in the IDE. The `systrace` python script is deprecated and not actively maintained.